# What is the acpi_pm linux clocksource used for, what hardware implements it?

Tags: linux, time, clock

The file `/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource` in my Linux box lists the following clock sources:

```
tsc hpet acpi_pm
```

I know that `tsc` is the Timestamp Counter Register in the Processer.
I know the `hpet` is the High Precision event timer.

I do not know what the `acpi_pm` is and what hardware implements it?  Is this the PIT (programmable interval timer)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's ACPI power management timer.

> The ACPI Power Management Timer (or ACPI PMT) is yet another clock device included in almost all ACPI-based motherboards. Its clock signal has a fixed frequency of roughly 3.58 MHz. The device is actually a simple counter increased at each clock tick

(from [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005658.do))

Comment: Thanks.  I seriously searched the web for an hour and could not find this.

Comment: makelinux link is dead now, can't find a new one